# Regex escape sequence error in Java

Tags: java, regex, escaping

```
p = "<a href=\".*?\"\\stitle=\"(.*?\")>.*?<\/a><span class=\"event-nodetype\">\((.*?\)</span><span class=\"event-timeleft\">\()(.*?\)<\/span><li>)";
```

This is regex i created for

```
<a href="/bu/?q=node/775" title="YOK ED?LEN MEDEN?YET: GEÇ OSMANLI VE ERKEN CUMHUR?YET DÖNEMLER?NDE GAYR?MÜSL?M VARLI?I">YOK ED?LEN MEDEN?YET: GEÇ OSMANLI VE ERKEN CUMHUR?YET DÖNEMLER?NDE GAYR?MÜSL?M VARLI?I</a><span class="event-nodetype">(Konferans / Kongre / Sempozyum)</span><span class="event-timeleft">(Devam etmekte)</span><li>
```

But eclipse gives error of

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )
```

I put `\`  to `"` and other things but still i cant fix it.

What is the problem?

When i split the line into 4 lines

```
 p = "<a href=\".*?\"\\stitle=\"(.*?\")>"
        + ".*?<\/a><span class=\"event-nodetype\">\(("
        + ".*?\)</span><span class=\"event-timeleft\">\()("
        + ".*?\)<\/span><li>)";
```

the error seems on line 2.

Comment: There's an invalid escape sequence towards the end of the line: `<\/span>`

Comment: but in html </span><li>  i need to put that so i need that slash?and it did not change anything. Error seems at beginning because beginning of this line is red

Comment: It all depends in the language that you are using. The error message doesn't list a forward slash as one of the escaped sequences, so it's probably safe to say that you don't need to escape it here.

Comment: There is also this one on the second line of your edit: `<\/a>`

Comment: I did but this time eclipse doesnot give what i want. But according to http://regexr.com/, i could find 6 matches. Now none.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Ok i solved. Thanks elgavilian. Java eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

`\"` is correct, an so is `\\s` (but I would use `\\s+`).  All the other backslashes in your regex need to be escaped: `\\/`, `\\(`, `\\)` (`/` doesn't need escaping, but doing so doesn't hurt anything).  This is for the string literal, not for the regex; the backslash is an escape character for both.